# Calling fork in shared library

Tags: multithreading, shared-libraries, fork

It is generally safe to use `fork` inside of a shared library that will be called from another host process?

The shared library would fork in order to execute a procedure in parallel (with the additional protection of having separate memory spaces for the forked processes, unlike threads), and then kill the forked processes before exiting the procedure.

Are there any side effects to the host executable, if it is temporatily duplicated?

Also is there a way to port this to Windows using `CreateProcess`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, the rules for `fork()` are outlined in the [fork man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork). I don't believe there is a difference between calling `fork()` from within the core of your application and calling it from within a shared library. I.e., the child process will still be identical to the parent process except that it won't inherit the parent's memory locks, asynchronous I/O operations, etc. See [man fork](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) for details.

Here is an example C program which provides a `fork_wrapper()` function.

```
==> fork_wrapper.h <==
#include <unistd.h>     // For fork(), etc.

pid_t fork_wrapper();

==> fork_wrapper.c <==
// To compile: gcc -c -fpic -o fork_wrapper.o fork_wrapper.c && gcc -shared -o libfork_wrapper.so fork_wrapper.o
#include <stdlib.h>     // For exit()
#include <stdio.h>      // For I/O
#include <string.h>     // For strerror(), memcpy(), etc.
#include <errno.h>      // For errors reported by 'nix system calls.
#include <unistd.h>     // For fork(), etc.

pid_t fork_wrapper()
{
    pid_t child = fork();
    if (-1 == child)
    {
        printf("fork_wrapper: fork(): error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (0 == child)
    {
        printf("fork_wrapper: fork(): succeeded (child)\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("fork_wrapper: fork(): succeeded (parent)\n");
        return child;
    }
}

==> main.c <==
// To compile: gcc -L. -lfork_wrapper main.c -o main
#include "fork_wrapper.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    pid_t child = fork_wrapper();
    if (!child)
    {
        printf("fork_wrapper: waiting for child process\n");
        waitpid(-1, 0, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If exit is called in a shared library and the shared library has been loaded by another program then exit takes the whole lot down, which is not a great outcome.